# HTML Displays empty DIV element before function is executed

Tags: javascript, html, css

[Before function is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXAdN.png)

[After function is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIVEB.png)

Hey guys!

I have this weird behavior of a div element that holds text generated by a function.

Basically if you take a look at [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXAdN.png), empty div element is displayed that should be hidden until button is pressed.

If you take a look at [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIVEB.png), you can see how does it look when button is pressed.

I am not sure how to remove the white block div from showing up until user clicks on a button?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Show your code. Tell us what you've tried.

Comment: That's because your div has padding (in CSS)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById("div-class").style.display = "none";
```

you can manipulate dom elements via your javascript code. try to set display none.

Comment: This answer is not far away from deserving an upvote. But it's too short, there's no explanation, you just dropped a line of code, and deal with it. Try to improve the quality by explaining what this is and why it solves the problem.

Comment: i just added, thank you for your warning.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class of `hidden` to that div, and in css:

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

then on button click, remove that class.

```
document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener(function(e){
     
    // other lines 

    document.getElementById('thatdiv').classList.remove('hidden');     
     
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let quotes = [

  'The best thing about a boolean is even if you are wrong, you are only off by a bit. (Anonymous)',
  'Without requirements or design, programming is the art of adding bugs to an empty text file. (Louis Srygley)',
  'Before software can be reusable it first has to be usable. (Ralph Johnson)',
  'The best method for accelerating a computer is the one that boosts it by 9.8 m/s2. (Anonymous)',
  'I think Microsoft named .Net so it wouldn’t show up in a Unix directory listing. (Oktal)',
  'If builders built buildings the way programmers wrote programs, then the first woodpecker that came along would destroy civilization. (Gerald Weinberg)',
  'There are two ways to write error-free programs; only the third one works. (Alan J. Perlis)',
  'Ready, fire, aim: the fast approach to software development. Ready, aim, aim, aim, aim: the slow approach to software development. (Anonymous)',
  'It’s not a bug – it’s an undocumented feature. (Anonymous)',
  'One man’s crappy software is another man’s full-time job. (Jessica Gaston)',
  'A good programmer is someone who always looks both ways before crossing a one-way street. (Doug Linder)',
  'Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live. (Martin Golding)',
  'Programming is like sex. One mistake and you have to support it for the rest of your life. (Michael Sinz)',
  'Deleted code is debugged code. (Jeff Sickel)',
  'Walking on water and developing software from a specification are easy if both are frozen. (Edward V Berard)',
  'If debugging is the process of removing software bugs, then programming must be the process of putting them in. (Edsger Dijkstra)',
  'Software undergoes beta testing shortly before it’s released. Beta is Latin for “still doesn’t work. (Anonymous)',
  'Programming today is a race between software engineers striving to build bigger and better idiot-proof programs, and the universe trying to produce bigger and better idiots. So far, the universe is winning. (Rick Cook)',
  'It’s a curious thing about our industry: not only do we not learn from our mistakes, but we also don’t learn from our successes. (Keith Braithwaite)',
  'There are only two kinds of programming languages: those people always bitch about and those nobody uses. (Bjarne Stroustrup)',
  'In order to understand recursion, one must first understand recursion. (Anonymous)',
  'The cheapest, fastest, and most reliable components are those that aren’t there. (Gordon Bell)',
  'The best performance improvement is the transition from the nonworking state to the working state. (J. Osterhout)',
  'The trouble with programmers is that you can never tell what a programmer is doing until it’s too late. (Seymour Cray)',
  'Don’t worry if it doesn’t work right. If everything did, you’d be out of a job. (Mosher’s Law of Software Engineering)'
];

function genQuote() {

  // Selecing an element from HTML
  let quote = document.querySelector('#quote-content');

  // Creating an indexQ of a random number
  // And floor it between 0 to length of quotes[]
  let indexQ = Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length);

  // Display the quote of that index
  quote.innerHTML = quotes[indexQ];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #8BC6EC;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, #8BC6EC 0%, #9599E2 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#quote-content {
  font-size: 22px;
}

.btn {
  background: url(/img/favicon1.png) no-repeat;
  border: none;
  width: 102px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: none;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.btn:active {
  opacity: .2;
}

.card {
  padding: 15px 30px 15px 30px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  max-height: 300px;
  background-color: #f2e6ff;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.card>h2 {
  color: #ffeeee;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 28px;
  background-color: #5390d9;
  font-family: arial;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px #023e8a;
}

.card>p {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/quotes.png">
  <title>Coding Quotes</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <h2>Random quote</h2>
      <p>Generate random quote!</p>
      <button onclick="genQuote()" class="btn"></button>
    </div>
    <div id="quote-content" class="card"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Somebody mentioned that this happens because div (class="card") has a padding in CSS.
I've tested removing the padding and it actually does the trick however, it kinda ruins the way card looks.

I have attached the code so if anybody has any tip/advice, I'm open to it! :)